evaluate using the output coordinates of \tdplottransformrotmain in the evaluate <> as <> using of a \foreach loop
How can I evaluate using the output coordinates of \tdplottransformrotmain in the evaluate <> as <> using of a \foreach loop?
For instance, how could I manipulate example 2 in my code to make the same output as example 1?
I'm trying to follow through on the advice here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728029/319072.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot,comment}
\newcommand{\sphereX}[2]{cos(#2)*cos(#1)}
\newcommand{\sphereY}[2]{cos(#2)*sin(#1)}
\newcommand{\sphereZ}[2]{sin(#2)}
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% EXAMPLE 1 %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{30}
\pgfextra{
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{30}{30}{30}
  \tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{0}{60}}{\sphereY{0}{60}}{\sphereZ{0}{60}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\tdplotresx}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\tdplotresy}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastz{\tdplotresz}
  \foreach \Vt in {0,10,...,350}{
    \tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{\Vt}{60}}{\sphereY{\Vt}{60}}{\sphereZ{\Vt}{60}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Vx{\tdplotresx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Vy{\tdplotresy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\Vz{\tdplotresz}
    \draw (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- (\Vx,\Vy,\Vz);
    \pgfmathsetmacro\lastx{\Vx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\lasty{\Vy}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\lastz{\Vz}
    \global\let\lastx\lastx
    \global\let\lasty\lasty
    \global\let\lastz\lastz
  } % ends foreach
} % ends pgfextra
\end{tikzpicture}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% EXAMPLE 2 %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{30}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{30}{30}{30}
\pgfextra{
  \tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{0}{60}}{\sphereY{0}{60}}{\sphereZ{0}{60}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastix{\tdplotresx}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastiy{\tdplotresy}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastiz{\tdplotresz}
  \foreach \Vt [
    % I want to transform the points using something like this:
    % \tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{\Vt}{60}}{\sphereY{\Vt}{60}}{\sphereZ{\Vt}{60}}
    evaluate=\Vt as \Vx using {\tdplotresx},%
    evaluate=\Vt as \Vy using {\tdplotresy},%
    evaluate=\Vt as \Vz using {\tdplotresz},%
    remember=\Vx as \lastx (initially \lastix),
    remember=\Vy as \lasty (initially \lastiy),
    remember=\Vz as \lasty (initially \lastiz)
    ]  in {10,20,...,350}{
    \draw (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- (\Vx,\Vy,\Vz);
  } % ends foreach
} % ends pgfextra
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I'm not sure what you want to do with \pgfextra{} but, whatever it is, it isn't doing anything in your MWE. If you look at the output on the terminal, you will see that tikz tries to typeset pgfextra and complains none of these characters exist in the current font (which is the null font inside a tikzpicture, so contains no characters whatsoever).
I don't know if it is possible to do the transformation as part of an evaluate, but I don't see the point. Do the transformation inside the loop. You don't need the \Vx etc. you can use the resulting coordinates directly and save those directly in the loop invocation.
  \foreach \Vt [
    remember=\tdplotresx as \lastx (initially \lastix),
    remember=\tdplotresy as \lasty (initially \lastiy),
    remember=\tdplotresz as \lastz (initially \lastiz),
  ]  in {10,20,...,350}{

Now transform.
    \tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{\Vt}{60}}{\sphereY{\Vt}{60}}{\sphereZ{\Vt}{60}}

and use the resulting and remembered coordinates
    \draw (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz);
  } % ends foreach

and end the loop.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\newcommand{\sphereX}[2]{cos(#2)*cos(#1)}
\newcommand{\sphereY}[2]{cos(#2)*sin(#1)}
\newcommand{\sphereZ}[2]{sin(#2)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tdplotsetmaincoords{30}{30}
  \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{30}{30}{30}
  \tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{0}{60}}{\sphereY{0}{60}}{\sphereZ{0}{60}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastix{\tdplotresx}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastiy{\tdplotresy}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\lastiz{\tdplotresz}
  \foreach \Vt [
    remember=\tdplotresx as \lastx (initially \lastix),
    remember=\tdplotresy as \lasty (initially \lastiy),
    remember=\tdplotresz as \lastz (initially \lastiz),
  ]  in {10,20,...,350}{
    \tdplottransformrotmain{\sphereX{\Vt}{60}}{\sphereY{\Vt}{60}}{\sphereZ{\Vt}{60}}
    \draw (\lastx,\lasty,\lastz) -- (\tdplotresx,\tdplotresy,\tdplotresz);
  } % ends foreach
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

This gives the same output (as far as I can tell) as your first example.

Ah, I see, you can just use remember and calculate the second point inside the loop instead of using evaluate. Thank you, this will shorten my code significantly. Please pardon me not noticing this workaround.

Regarding the \pgfextra, it seems to be the only way to be able to use the \tdplotresx/y/z points after creating them. Your code seems to work just fine though. I must have missed something early on.

@Jasper so why don't I need them? :-) when I compiled your original example, \pgfextra was not interpreted as a command at all. tex tried to typeset it. so it cannot possibly be necessary in order to use those coordinates. you can run my example for yourself and see as much ;).

I'm going to try to find the example which led me to believe this and see what I got wrong. Thank you for clarifying this
